# How to convert returned query result from Salesforce SOAP API to Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, api, apache-spark, soap, salesforce

I am trying to convert query result of an object (retrieved through Salesforce SOAP API) to Spark dataframe.

below is sample code from Salesforce site, it's in Java, what I expect is transforming 'records'(com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.SObject) to dataframe, so I'm able to run it as script in Spark-Shell for test purpose

Thanks,

```
   private void querySample() {
        String soqlQuery = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact";
        QueryResult qr = connection.query(soqlQuery);
        if (qr.getSize() > 0) {
            SObject[] records = qr.getRecords();
            for (int i = 0; i < records.length; ++i) {
                Contact con = (Contact) records[i];
                String fName = con.getFirstName();
                String lName = con.getLastName();
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: I don't know how Salesforce objects look like, but to interface with Spark, you can use the JDBC connector of salesforce at https://www.cdata.com/drivers/salesforce/jdbc/ . You can simply run queries through the JDBC connector and get your results directly as a Spark dataframe

Comment: Hi @mck, Yes, the jdbc is much easier, but the testing environment provides SOAP API access only, no other choice.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but there has to be a way to do it, since Spark is frequently accessed via Scala, which is a JVM language.